# How to use valgrind or gdb to find double free error in omxplayer

Tags: debugging, gdb, valgrind

I have a complicated build of omxplayer where I use tcp communication to synchronize multiple instances of omxplayer across multiple computers. Currently, when I run the master/slave setup I get the following error on my server (master):

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/omxplayer.bin: double free or corruption (!prev): 0x00dc4ba0 ***
```

I want to eventually debug this with either gdb or valgrind. Before tackling that, I tried to see if it would at least work on the simplest omxplayer command, `omxplayer foo.mp4`. Unfortunately, both of them give me the below errors.

**gdb output:**

```
gdb omxplayer.bin
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/omxplayer.bin...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run 1.mp4
Starting program: /usr/bin/omxplayer.bin 1.mp4
/usr/bin/omxplayer.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.55: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Inferior 1 (process 4460) exited with code 0177]
(gdb) quit
```

**valgrind output:**

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck omxplayer  1.mp4
==4497== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4497== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4497== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4497== Command: /usr/bin/omxplayer /home/raspi/media/video/clips/1.mp4
==4497== 
disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xF1010200
                 cond=15(0xF) 27:20=16(0x10) 4:4=0 3:0=0(0x0)
==4497== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4843588.
==4497==    at 0x4843588: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so)
==4497== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==4497== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==4497== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==4497==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==4497==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==4497== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==4497==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==4497==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==4497== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==4497== probably kill your program.
==4497== 
==4497== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==4497==  Illegal opcode at address 0x4843588
==4497==    at 0x4843588: ??? (in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libcofi_rpi.so)
==4497== 
==4497== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4497==     in use at exit: 388 bytes in 25 blocks
==4497==   total heap usage: 25 allocs, 0 frees, 388 bytes allocated
==4497== 
==4497== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4497==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4497==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4497==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4497==    still reachable: 388 bytes in 25 blocks
==4497==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4497== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4497== 
==4497== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4497== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 6)
Illegal instruction
```

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** To be clear, the command `omxplayer foo.mp4` does indeed work

Comment: NOTE: The program is written in C++, but the last question I tagged as C/C++ some guy lost it claiming that it was tagged incorrectly on account of being about language beautifiers and not exactly/entirely C/C++. Therefore, I leave it to someone else to tag this as C++

Comment: As for this: `error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.55`. In gdb before running your program run this command: `set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/folder/with/this/library` and then run your program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> /usr/bin/omxplayer.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.55

This error means that the dynamic loader failed to find `libavcodec.so.55` (not a big surprise).

This happens most often when you set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `.bashrc` (gdb invokes a *new* shell, and runs your program in that shell).

Solutions:

- build omxplayer.bin such that you don't need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the first place, by adding appropriate `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/dir-with-libavcodec` to its link line
- Add the directory where `libavcodec.so.55` resides to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and rerun `/sbin/ldconfig`
- Don't touch `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in your `.bashrc` when using non-interactive shell
- set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately from within GDB:

  `(gdb) set env LD_LIBRARY_PATH /path/to/dir-with-libavcodec`

> disInstr(arm): unhandled instruction: 0xF1010200

That is a bug in Valgrind. Try building a newer version, and if still present, report it to Valgrind developers.

Finally, to find the actual double-free, you can try [AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/).

Comment: Thanks, I will try out all of those later today. With respect to `-Wl,-rpath=` what path am I supposed to put in there (more or less)?

Comment: Your fourth solution did not help. I think it may have to do with the fact that omxplayer.bin is never called directly but through the shell script omxplayer